# it's possible to manage the responsive in the JS as in the CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

Good morning all.
I have a problem on my home page of my site I have a button when we click on it the size changes (done in the JS) then in responsive when the page is smaller I reduced the size of the button except that when I click on it takes the size I gave it for the big page.
And is it possible to manage the responsive in the JS as in the CSS?

Comment: kindly be clear in your question, need more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can use plain javascript code to check window size and apply your code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Chaning background on the window size</h1>

<script>
function resize(size) {
  if (size.matches) 
  {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  } 
  else 
  {
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
  }
}

var size = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)")
resize(size)
size.addListener(resize)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```